# Getting dispatch_failed error in slack when using slash command

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

So I have been trying to make a very simple slash command since last 3 days that just triggers a lambda function using an api gateway. The lambda function is quite simple too. I am following the below tutorial to make this

https://medium.com/@farski/learn-aws-api-gateway-with-the-slack-police-ca8d636e9fc0

Before this I have tried many myself with a just hello work lambda function, but no matter what whenever I try to run the command in slack I always get this "dispatch_failed" error.

```
/appname failed with the error "dispatch_failed"
```

As you can see this is se generic I dont know whats going wrong in this. Looks like slack is not even hitting the request url which I configured, i am not sure though. Anyone has ever faced this and knows how we can resolve this? Thanks

(The endpoint of api gateway works fine if I just use browser or postman)

P.S If you can suggest any tutorial that shows me how can I integrate slash command with api gateway and lambda, then please.

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I am stuck on a similar problem. Thanks!

Comment: @nit yup. Whats your scenario btw? Can you please tell me so I will be able to guide.

Comment: I am using bolt with Springboot and keep getting this error. I don't know where to see the errors. With normal https post mapping it seems to work ok. I should mention though that my springboot version is 2.0.x, which is lower than what was recommended.

Comment: This is a general error from slack and it usually comes when something goes wrong on the slack side. They just dont tell you what went wrong and simply show this error.

Answer (score -3):

Use **HTTP API** you might have using REST API.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).